# How can I add extra \pagemark that marks the number of the page where current chapter starts and where it ends?

Tags: cross-referencing, header-footer, page-numbering

I'm using KOMA-Script scrbook class. And scrpage2 package for headings:

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead[]{\headmark}
```

I want to add an extra pagemark on ofoot. The extra pagemark I need is like this:
pp. 181-195, where 181 is the page number where current chapter starts and 195 is where chapter ends. Of course, I need this to change in every chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a drop-in solution. However, you could do the following:

0) Define `\currchapternick` at the beginning of your document:

```
\newcommand{\currchapternick}{}
```

1) Surround each chapter by the following:

```
\renewcommand{\currchapternick}{unique-nick-for-chapter}
\label{begin-\currchapternick}
...
\label{end-\currchapternick}
```

2) Set `ofoot` as follows:

```
\ofoot[pp.~\pageref{begin-\currchapternick}--\pageref{end-\currchapternick}]%
      {pp.~\pageref{begin-\currchapternick}--\pageref{end-\currchapternick}}
```

I have tested the use of macros inside `\label` and `\ref` -- works. The code will produce the desired results if the contents of the footer are expanded lazily, which I presume. If not, you could still call `\ofoot` at the beginning of each chapter, as above.

According to [this](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/Hook-for-Executing-Code-at-End-of-Chapter) discussion in the mail archives, there is no such thing as `\AtBeginChapter` or `\AtEndChapter`, and hence no way to further automate this unless you delve deeply into TeX internals.

Comment: Note that this problem and its solution also works outside of KOMA and scrpage2.

Comment: Thank you! That works fine. Note: \rfoot is not an existing option. I've changed it on my question.

Comment: ...so I've edited my answer. Do you have to call `\ofoot` for each chapter, or does it suffice to call it once?

Comment: It suffice to call it once.

Comment: @user946850: Note that your solution doesn't work perfectly if `\chapter` (or, more precisely, `\cleardoublepage`) inserts an empty page before the chapter heading.

Comment: That depends on your notion of "perfect". If a chapter's trailing page is blank, does it belong to the chapter or not? I think it doesn't, or, fwiw, it doesn't _matter_. If you require consecutive page ranges, you could try to compute the smallest even (or odd) number not smaller than `pageref{end-\currchapternick}` using the `calc` package.

Comment: I have this code `\renewcommand{\currchapternick}{Elsigno}
\label{end-\currchapternick}
\cleardoublepage  
\phantomsection
\setcounter{footnote}{0} \chapter` And I can say it works fine.

Comment: @Mario: If `\chapter` inserts an empty page before the chapter heading (due to the `open=right` class option) the end label marks the page before that page. But, as user946850 has pointed out it's a matter of taste whether you consider the last empty page of a chapter as part of the chapter at all.

Comment: @mhp OK, you are right. I understand now what you say. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For this task and similar ones, the `zref` package comes in handy. Based on the `abspage` and `thepage` modules provided by this package, you can define a macro `\chappagerangelabel` as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[abspage, thepage]{zref}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}% lorem ipsum placeholder text

\makeatletter

\newcounter{chappagerange}% auxiliary counter

\newcounter{chappointer}% auxiliary counter
\stepcounter{chappointer}% value 1 for first chapter

\newcommand*{\chappagerangelabel}{%
  \zref@label{chappagerange:\the\value{chappointer}}%
  \setcounter{chappagerange}{\zref@extract{chappagerange:\the\value{chappointer}}{abspage}}%
  \edef\thechappagerange{\zthepage{\the\value{chappagerange}}}% first page
  \stepcounter{chappointer}%
  \setcounter{chappagerange}{\zref@extract{chappagerange:\the\value{chappointer}}{abspage}-1}%
  \edef\thechappagerange{pp.~\thechappagerange--\zthepage{\the\value{chappagerange}}}% first page--last page
}
```

Now, define a macro `\pagerangemark` modelled after `\pagemark`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\pagerangemark}{%
  {\pnumfont\thechappagerange}%
}

\makeatother
```

Put `\chappagerangelabel` at the very beginning of each chapter and immediately after the last chapter and use `\pagerangemark` in `\ofoot`:

```
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\clearscrheadfoot
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead[]{\headmark}

\frontmatter

\noindent
Text

\mainmatter

\ofoot[\pagerangemark]{\pagerangemark}

\chapter{A Chapter}
\chappagerangelabel

\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{Another Chapter}
\chappagerangelabel

\lipsum[21-40]

\backmatter

\chappagerangelabel

\ofoot[]{}

\noindent
Text

\end{document}
```

Note that this solution does not allow for the case that the last page of the last chapter is also the last page of the whole document. Apart from that, it should work smoothly.

Comment: Now we're halfway towards a new, fully generic `sectionranges` package, aren't we? :-) Given that you forgot `\makeatletter`...

Comment: Now I see, you call `\makeatletter` in your preamble. Missed that. Anyway, it would be nice to see a package that encapsulates and automates the above logic.